# No injective path between the two origins of the "line with two origins".

Tags: general-topology

During my preparations for my topology exam, I came across the following exercise:

Let L denote the *line with two origins*. Show that there is no injective path between the two origins $0_{-}$ and $0_{+}$. I tried to prove it by contradiction as follows:

I have already shown that $L$ is not Hausdorff, in particular, we cannot separate the two origins. So any subspace containing both origins cannot be Hausdorff. Assume that there exists an injective path $\gamma: [0,1] \to L$ from $0_{-}$ to $0_{+}$. Then $\gamma: [0,1] \to \gamma([0,1])$ is bijective and $\gamma([0,1])$ is a subspace of $L$ containing both origins.

Now I tried to show, that $\gamma: [0,1] \to \gamma([0,1])$ is actually a local homeomorphism which then would lead to a contradiction. However, I failed to do so. Is this the right approach for this exercise and how can I show that $\gamma^{-1}$ is continuous.

I somehow have the feeling that I miss some triviality...

Comment: Your approach sounds fine, but notice that $\gamma$ is an injective, continuous, closed map, and therefore an [embedding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#General_topology). This yields your contradiction.

Comment: The claim "any subspace containing both origins cannot be Hausdorff" is not correct - consider for example $\{0_-,0_+\}$. To solve the exercise I would use two steps. First, show that the image of the path needs to contain a point $p$ other than $0_-$ and $0_+$. Second, show that in order to go from $0_-$ to $p$ (as well as from $p$ to $0^+$) you need to pass from all the points in between.

Comment: Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how we can show that $\gamma$ should be a local homeomorphism, but I have something else for you. The idea is that $\gamma$ cannot 'cross' the origin. $\gamma([0,1/2))$ and $\gamma([1/2,1])$ are connected, disjoint subsets of $L$. So one of them is contained in $(-\infty,0)$ and the other one is contained in $(0,\infty)$. Find a contradiction by examining the value of $\gamma(1/2)$, using the continuity of $\gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

The injectivity will give a contradiction. Notice that if we subtract the two origins from $\gamma ([0,1])$, then we obtain a continuous injection from the connected set $(0,1)$ into the union of connected components $(-\infty ,0)\cup (0,\infty )$, so we have $\gamma (0,1)\subset (-\infty ,0)$ for example, but this will give a contradiction since this will mean that the set $(-\varepsilon ,0)$ for $\varepsilon $ sufficient close to $0$ will contain elements of $\gamma (0,1)$ both for $t$ close to $1$ and $t$ close to $0$, and connectedness implies that $(0,\delta )$ for some $\delta $ will be mapped into $(-\varepsilon ,0)$, so there must not be any elements of $\gamma (t)$ for $t$ close to $1$ in this neighbourhood.

Comment: Thank you for this straight-forward answer.